# How to remove double quotes from batch script argument?

Tags: windows, batch-file

If I have a script like so:
`set test=%1`

and test is "Path/To/File.exe blah blah2 blah3" how can I remove the quotes around the argument? Passing it with quotes is necessary because it's just another command I want to run, but once it's been converted as a whole argument, I need to remove the quotes so that it will run.

Comment: Try ```set "test=%~1"```

Comment: `set "test=%~1"`    ....

Comment: Type `call /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the usage text; you'll find out how to use `~`-modifiers…